# Returning callback from service to component in React + Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Have a question about the proper implementation of Flux with ReactJS.

Lets say I have a contact form which calls my ContactService on submit, passing the form information.

ContactService.js

```
import request from 'superagent';
import when from 'when';
import ContactActions from '../actions/';

let constants = require('../constants.js');
const BASE_URL = constants.default.BASE_URL;

class ContactService {

  submitFormData(formData) {
    request
    .get(BASE_URL + 'api/v1/contact') 
    .end(function(err, res){
      if (!err && res){
        // This is where my question is
      } else {
        console.log("There has been an error submitting contact form to API");
        console.log(err)
        // This is also kind of where my question is
      }
    })
  }
}

export default new ContactService();
```

Now, I want to notify my component whether the submission was successful. My question is what is the best way to do that? If I were retrieving data from the API, or needed to change the state of my component, I would handle it by passing the response to an Action, and saving the data in Store, which the component could subscribe to.

But here I just need a response so that I can show a confirmation or error message. Should that still be passed through an action and store? Or is there a better way, like returning a promise directly to the component so that it can run a callback function without involving the store at all?

Comment: No, never return data from action, action is `fire and forget`

Comment: I'm calling the service directly from the component though, so I'd be returning data from the service, not from the action.

Answer (score 0):

Always use store/flux actions for that kind of thing.

Dispatch a `data_received`, `data_error` from the Promise handlers. It's more semantic, easier to debug and uses the same flow of data as everything else (action -> store -> view).

Answer (score 0):

All the data retrieving in a flux architecture has to be done through stores and actions